# TypeScript complaining that the --module isn't being provided even though module is set to "common.js"

Tags: typescript

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs", // module is set here
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "nlp-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./out/script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "compromise": "^13.0.0",
    "compromise-ngrams": "0.0.5",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.2",
    "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
    "tslint": "^6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
}
```

This is my `script.ts`:

```
import compromise from 'compromise'
import ngrams from 'compromise-ngrams'

const nlp = compromise.extend(ngrams)

const ngram = nlp('test is test').ngrams({ min: 1 })
console.log(ngram)
```

When I do `tsc script/script.ts` in my terminal, I get this error:

```
src/script.ts(1,1): error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
src/script.ts(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'compromise'.
src/script.ts(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'compromise-ngrams'.
```

Strangely, if I do `ts-node src/script.ts`, the code runs.

What could be the reason, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does it work, when you just write `tsc` without args?

Comment: @ford04 Oh, now I get: `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'strict'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'esModuleInterop'.` Even though I just installed `tsc` and `Typescript`.

Comment: I don't even know what that `tsc` package is, `typescript` is the usual way to go. Have you tried uninstalling `tsc`?

Comment: @ford04 Oh that worked ... I think I shouldn't have written `tsc` with arguments since I had a `tsconfig` file. Could you post an answer, so I can vote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to only install the [`typescript`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) npm package and use the node executable `tsc` CLI script contained in it. And you didn't mean to install the *npm package* [`tsc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc).

In addition, `tsc script/script.ts` won't use your tsconfig.json, as described in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#overview):

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json files are ignored.

Instead just leave out the file and use `tsc`. `ts-node` loads `tsconfig.json` [automatically](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#loading-tsconfigjson).

Cheers!